# C# - Passing object selected in ComboBox to next form

Tags: c#, object, combobox

I want my Login form to pass the object selected in the ComboBox to the Profile Editor form when the Log In button is clicked.

Form has three elements: 
Exit button 
Login button
ComboBox - contains a list of user profiles

```
        var employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        comboBox1.DataSource = employeeList;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

This is how I've got it set up to display the profiles right now.
I want the selected profile to be the only one accessible on the second form, where I have controls to edit a few bool values for the specified object.

How do I write this so that I'm only editing one profile at a time on the second form?

Edit: Idle_Mind's comments helped me get to the point where I'm successfully passing the correct Employee object into the Profile Editor form. The problem now is that I can't use that Employee object outside of this block of code:

```
       public ProfileEditor(Employee emp)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Employee currentProfile = emp;
    }
```

I had planned to use that currentProfile object to alter a few boolean values in each object, but currentProfile.isAvailable = true doesn't work outside this block of code.

Edit 2: currentProfile is now accessible to all controls on Profile Editor.
And now, my dreaded nemesis, the inconsistent accessibility error. 
"Parameter type 'SchedulingApp.Employee' is less accessible than method 'SchedulingApps.Forms.ProfileEditor.ProfileEditor(SchedulingApp.Employee)'"
My Employee class, for reference.

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private bool isAdmin = false;
    public bool[,] isAvailable = new bool[7, 3]
   {           //  Day   Swing  Night
   /*Sunday*/    {false, false, false},
   /*Monday*/    {false, false, false},
   /*Tuesday*/   {false, false, false},
   /*Wednesday*/ {false, false, false},
   /*Thursday*/  {false, false, false},
   /*Friday*/    {false, false, false},
   /*Saturday*/  {false, false, false} 
   };

    public Employee (string m_name)
{
    employeeList = new List<Employee>();
    Name = m_name;
}
    public Employee (string m_name, bool manager)
    {
        Name = m_name;
        isAdmin = manager;
    }
```

}

Comment: Cast .SelectedItem to Employee and pass that to the Constructor of your Profile Editor.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with casting, could you give me a one-liner as an example? would it be something like Employee selection as combobox1.selecteditem

Comment: Something like: `Employee emp = (Employee)comboBox1.SelectedItem;`  There is more than one to way to cast things...  =)

Comment: And then I would i would just make a new editor form with emp as a parameter, and I should be able to edit the passed profile, correct?

Comment: Profile editor won't recognize the Employee object outside the initialize method block.

Comment: Can't help you without seeing the code.  Usual solution is to declare an Employee variable at the Form level in your Profile Editor, then copy the reference in the Constructor to the variable so it can be used throughout the Form.

Comment: Put `public` in front of `class Employee` so you have `public class Employee`.

Comment: Will you post something as an answer so I can flag it? :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1:
Cast .SelectedItem to Employee and pass that to the Constructor of your Profile Editor.

Something like:

```
Employee emp = (Employee)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Issue 2:
Usual solution is to declare an Employee variable at the Form level in your Profile Editor, then copy the reference in the Constructor to the variable so it can be used throughout the Form.

Issue 3:
Put `public` in front of `class Employee` so you have `public class Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static Employee variable in the ProfileEditor form:

```
public partial class ProfileEditor : Form
{
    public static Employee emp;
    public ProfileEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then immediately before you show the ProfileEditor form, set the variable to your selected Employee:

```
ProfileEditor.emp = combobox1.SelectedItem as Employee;
ProfileEditor pe = new ProfileEditor();
pe.Show(this);
```

You now have the selected employee object available on the Profile Editor form.

Comment: Sorry dude, you're a bit late to the party. Idle_Mind helped me through all of this, he just never posted anything as an answer until now.

Comment: Duly noted, dude.  I will make sure to not provide alternate solutions to the problems you are facing in the future.  My apologies.